# How to rename n rows occurring before a certain value in a column?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with around 60000 entries and a column (2) containing values of 0 and 1. I would like to assign value 3 to every 12 rows that occur just before value 1. The values of 0 and 1 do not occur regularly in my dataset.

```
 1. 0
 2. 0
 3. 0
 4. 0
 5. 0
 6. 0
 7. 0
 8. 0
 9. 0
 10. 0
 11. 0
 12. 0
 13. 1
 14. 0
 15. 0
```

In the example above, I would like to assign value 3 to rows from 1 - 12:

```
 1. 3
 2. 3
 3. 3
 4. 3
 5. 3
 6. 3
 7. 3
 8. 3
 9. 3
 10. 3
 11. 3
 12. 3
 13. 1
 14. 0
 15. 0
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more extensive example? Does this algorithm apply just to first 13 rows or a span of any 13 consecutive zeros?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: I have tried many different functions before, so please do not jump to conclusions that I'm treating this as a code-writing service. My attempts were not successful and wouldn't help anyone to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sapply to check the condition for every row in your dataframe:

```
dt <- data.frame(x = rep(c(rep(0,15),1),5))

dt$y <- if_else(sapply(seq_len(nrow(dt)), function(x) {any(dt[(x+1):(x+12),'x']==1)}),3,dt$x)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(var1 = sample(c(0,1), 100, T, c(0.97, 0.03)))
df$var1[sapply(which(df$var1 == 1), function(x) seq(x -1, x-12))] <- 3

head(df, 25)
   var1
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     0
9     0
10    0
11    0
12    3
13    3
14    3
15    3
16    3
17    3
18    3
19    3
20    3
21    3
22    3
23    3
24    1
25    0
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works!

Comment: Your welcome. Please consider to upvote or accept the answer if it was helpful to you. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers